# Why do I have to multiply by 1000 to get the unix stamp in readable format?

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I have this unix timestamp "1512046197"
If I multiply it by 1000 I get the unix timestamp in readable format but I do not understand why I have to use 1000 and not 100 or 10.

```
console.log(new Date("1512046197" * 1000)
```

Comment: That date constructor wants *milliseconds*, so seconds * 1000 is appropriate

Answer (score 2):

A UNIX timestamp is the number of seconds elapsed from January 1st 1970.

JavaScript's `Date` constructor wants the number of milliseconds elapsed from January 1st 1970. If you have a number in seconds, of course, you have to multiply it by 1000.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript date constructor syntax is

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

That is why you need to pass milliseconds.

Thanks.